# Get Android app launch source from Application context

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, lifecycle

Is it possible from the Application class onCreate method (not Activity!!) to identify how the app has been launched?, like if it was from the Launcher or Push Notification or a boot complete broadcast receiver etc'

Also, is there a way to get the Intent object (if exists) which caused the launch, from the Application onCreate?

Basically what I am interested is to recognize if it was from Launcher or not and get the Intent if exists. All this, in the Application class, and not Activity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't believe it's possible to check whether the app has been launched by the launcher directly, but rather with a process of elimination.
Technically there is a way to get the Intent, which was used to launch the App in the Application's onCreate.

Since you can use Intent to start Activities, not Applications, you can use [registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) to register an [onActivityCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks#onActivityCreated(android.app.Activity,%20android.os.Bundle)) callback in your App's onCreate, which gives you access to the created activity.
Once you have the activity object, you can call activity.getIntent() to get the Intent object.

The `onActivityCreated` callback also gives you a savedInstanceState Bundle, which you can utilize to determine, whether the App was already running before or not.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I am afraid I don't know if I can adopt this approach. Actually, this is a ReactNative app, which has single Activity and Application. what I need is to check if the launch was NOT from the Launcher and then invoke some task in the JS part of the app, otherwise no action should be done. So does asynchronous callback can be used for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't know about React Native. I suppose you can't utilize all the native application and activity methods, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Well I can say that I did find one way.. and it's by gettingSystemSrvice(ACTIVITY_SREVICE) and from there I did got the package name of the most top activity and compare it to the Application package..  Surprisingly when the app was launched not from Launcher, there was some activity but it has different package name. This approach really smells..